# How to assign parameters in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

There is definitely something that I am missing. I was hoping if you could help me with that.

Code:

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<char, string>> GroupByProperty()
        {
            string[] words = {"blueberry", "chimpanzee", "abacus", "banana", "apple", "cheese"};

            IEnumerable<IGrouping<char, string>> query = from w in words
                                                         group w by w[0] into g
                                                         select (letter = g.Key, word = g);

            return query;
        }
```

The select method throws an error "you can't do that" (letter, word does not exist in the current context). I was wondering how to make select to understand that g.Key should be a first parameter (char), and g as the second parameter in my query?

Answer (score 3):

Based on your return type, you only require to select the `g`. Use below query for that.

```
 IEnumerable<IGrouping<char, string>> query = from w in words
                                              group w by w[0] into g
                                              select g;
```

If you need to select the Key also then use below

```
  var query = from w in words
              group w by w[0] into g
              select new { letter = g.Key, word = g };
```

The above will return both properties as anonymous type which require new after select; also the above will return `IEnumerable<<anonmoystype: char, IGrouping<char, string>>` type not the `IEnumerable<IGrouping<char, string>>`

Comment: The latter code does not work, while the first one is not what I really need.

(Second code) results in a long error: 

"CS0266: Cannot implictely convert type 'System.Collections.Generics.IEnumerable<<anonymous type: char, System.Linq.IGrouping<char, string>word>> ' to 'System.Collections.Generics.Ienumerable<System.Linq.Igrouping<char,string>>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" 

-- I tried to cast explicitly -- no luck

Comment: @Dibldop - I did mentioned the return type of second query. If you require the return type as `IEnumerable<IGrouping<char, string>>` then use the first one. For second one, change your return type or use `var` keyword.